Logic apps - how to read 2 rows through an index variable
json input -
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "primaryresult",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "startdate",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "enddate",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "rows": [
        [
          "01/01/2014",
          "31/01/2014"
        ],
        [
          "01/02/2014",
          "28/02/2014"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}

i need to get out put -
[ {"startdate" : "01/01/2014", "enddate" : "31/01/2014"}, {"startdate" : "01/02/2014", "enddate" : "28/02/2014"} ]

need to arrive through index variables
I could able to read columns dates of startdate, enddate in the loops and dont know how to read rows - datas through indexvariable, and i dont want through hardcorded values.

If you want it to be completely dynamic then you need to do a lot of looping and index grabbing. If you know that you’re always going to have the two properties of start date and end date then you can just use the select operation.

Accepted and thanks for your valuable reply Skin

You can use below design which worked for me:

then:

Output:

Code View:
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": {
                    "tables": [
                        {
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "name": "startdate",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "enddate",
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            ],
                            "name": "primaryresult",
                            "rows": [
                                [
                                    "01/01/2014",
                                    "31/01/2014"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "01/02/2014",
                                    "28/02/2014"
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Select_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "from": "@range(0,length(body('Select')))",
                            "select": {
                                "@{body('Select')?[item()]}": "@items('For_each')?[item()]"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Select"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@first(outputs('Compose')?['tables'])?['rows']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Select": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Select": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@range(0,length(first(outputs('Compose')?['tables'])?['columns']))\r\n",
                    "select": "@first(outputs('Compose')?['tables'])?['columns']?[item()]?['name']"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Select"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}


Thanks for your well derived reply. I would like to get through index variable, loop through index variable by inner loops - items of array and out loop - rows array to achieve o/p,

yes it is item of array , you can then send the select 2 action details to the array

RithwikBojja - im getting o/p {
"body": [
{
"{"startdate":""}": "01/02/2014"
},
{
"{"enddate":""}": "28/02/2014"
}
]
} can suggest why? and mistake?

I don't know why you are getting that, if you get it, you can replace it ('') with no space ('') using replace function().

well and i have shorted out Rithwik

I'm going to assume that the structure of your JSON is always the same and you always have nothing more than the two dimensional array with the columns as they are.
If that's the case, make it easy in yourself and just use the Select operation.
Select Operation

These are the expressions within the step ...
From = first(outputs('Compose_JSON')['tables'])['rows']
StartDate = item()[0]
EndDate = item()[1]
Result

If you want to do it all dynamically then you'll need to do a lot of looping with some special functions thrown in for good measure.
Let me know if that helps.

Well and simply done Thanks. For better understanding wanna to do it all dynamically through loops.

Depending the size of your array, it will be extremely slow.  You're best to use another connector TBH.  You can use the in-line Javascript operation, or, if you're using LogicApps Standard and would prefer C#, then you can do it one of two ways there.
